# How do I remove "favorite" words from JSON API list after being selected?

Tags: javascript, json, xpath

I have a list of words (from a JSON API) being saved in a session variable (stored as a JSON array) as "favorite" words.

I need to be to remove those "favorite" words from being shown in the list after they are selected as a "favorite".

At the very least I would like to have the background change colors if the word is added to the "favorites" variable. How can I check the word in the API against the session variable of the "favorites"?

I thought I might be able to just change the path to the JSON API using xpath to only show words NOT in the session variable but not sure how this can be done or if thats even the best way.

Here is an example of the JSON API data (In XML)

```
<items>
  <item>
    <Rank>1</Rank>
    <Word>the</Word>
    <Partofspeech>adverb</Partofspeech>
    <Frequency>22038615</Frequency>
    <Dispersion>0.98</Dispersion>
  </item>
  <item>
    <Rank>2</Rank>
    <Word>be</Word>
    <Partofspeech>verb</Partofspeech>
    <Frequency>12545825</Frequency>
    <Dispersion>0.97</Dispersion>
  </item>
  <item>
    <Rank>3</Rank>
    <Word>and</Word>
    <Partofspeech>conjunction</Partofspeech>
    <Frequency>10741073</Frequency>
    <Dispersion>0.99</Dispersion>
  </item>
  <item>
    <Rank>4</Rank>
    <Word>of</Word>
    <Partofspeech>preposition</Partofspeech>
    <Frequency>10343885</Frequency>
    <Dispersion>0.97</Dispersion>
  </item>
</items>
```

The list is displayed and the user selects a "Word". The "Word" gets saved to a JSON array and stored as a session variable.

I need the API list above to be displayed but remove or hide the items that have been selected by the user and stored in the JSON array that is a session variable

Comment: Could you add some example code/JSON? That would be a good start.

Comment: Make ajax request when words are added/removed by user

Comment: added more detail and sample data in the post. As for ajax request...not sure how to do that

Comment: That is [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), not [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)... they are different data exchange formats. Does the API you are using also return JSON? Your question seems to imply it might. Is this question about how to filter JSON data or XML? XPath would only work with XML, not JSON; you could however filter JSON data using JS. What environment are you using this in? A browser? Node.js? Rhino? Browser support for XPath isn't great... although there is [a library for that](https://github.com/ilinsky/xpath.js).

Comment: I was just using the XML as an example of the word list data that I am storing as JSON when the user selects a "favorite" word. The favorites list is in JSON. I can switch to JSON for the master word list if needed. I just need to be able to take the JSON "favorite" data that is stored and remove it from the master list so the user cant select the "favorite" word again